# Calculating Variance and Standard Deviation with probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The age [in years] $X$ of sewing machines to be reconditioned is a random variable with the following probability distribution: $f(x)=(1/972)x(18-x)$ for $0<x<18,$ and $f(x)=0,$ elsewhere. The time [in months] for reconditioning a sewing machine, Y, is related to X by $Y=(X/9+.4).$

> $(i)$ Determine $E(X)$ and $\sigma_x$

What I did: First,

$E(X)=\int_{-{\infty}}^\infty$ $xf(x)dx$

$E(X)=$ $f(x)=(1/972)x(18-x)$

$=1/972\int_0^{18}x(18x-x^2)dx$

$=1/972[18x^3/3-x^4/4]_0^{18}$

**$E[X]=9$**

Next, $E(X^2)=\int_{-{\infty}}^\infty$ $x^2f(x)dx$

$=1/972\int_0^{18} x^2(18x-x^2)dx$

$=1/972[18x^4/4-x^5/5]_0^{18}$

$E[x^2]=97.2$

$Var(x)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=16.2$

**$\sigma_x = 4.02$**

> $(ii)$ Determine $E(Y)$ and $\sigma_y$

Using $Y=(X/9+.4),$ we get $E[Y]=(E[X]/9+.4)$

So, **$E[Y]=[9]/9+.4=1.4$**

> I am not sure how to calculate $\sigma_y$. Can someone please show me how this would be done with the working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variance formulae to calculate the variance, and then take the square root to find the standard deviation.

$V(Y)=V(\frac{X}{9}+.4)$

$V(Y)=V(\frac{X}{9})$ using the variance rules.

$V(Y)=\frac{1}{81}V(X)$ again using variance laws.

$V(Y)=\frac{1}{81}\times 16.2$

$V(Y) = 0.2$.

You can now calculate the standard deviation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It does help. I will vote for your answer.